# Use default predicate in WHERE method

Tags: c#, linq

Can I use a default predicate in the `where` method?

In my db I have a column `IsDeleted` for every tables. Is there a way when i get some data like this

```
_dbContext.Person.Where(x => x.Age > 35).FirstOrDefault();
```

it will also use another predicate like `x.IsDeleted == false` by default?

Comment: Do you mean you want LINQ to magically add `&& x.IsDeleted == false` to every one of your queries?

Comment: You can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Answer (score 0):

The `FirstOrDefault` method is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>` and returns either the first object in the enumeration, or the value represented by `default (T)` ([default keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default))

In your case, since the `T` is the class `Person`, it's default value is `null`

Reference for [default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table)

So to answer your question, no, it will not use any additional default predicates because that's not what `FirstOrDefault` does..

Answer (score 0):

You can add another condition in your Where lambda:

```
MyObject result = obj.Where(x => { return x.Age > 35 && x.IsDeleted == false; }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also you can use DefaultValue attribute for your Person object:

```
[DefaultValue(false)]
 public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
```